# Postgres users, roles and permissions

Tags: postgresql, database-permissions

I have recently moved hosting environments and have had to backup the old Postgres database and copied it to the new server.

On the new server, I imported the database and now I receive an error `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: permission denied for relation django_site` when accessing the site.

I believe this is because of owner on the tables if I do a `\l` I can see the owner is the correct user `userW2E`

```
      Name      |  Owner   | Encoding |  Collate   |   Ctype    |   Access privileges
----------------+----------+----------+------------+------------+-----------------------
 hypersrvdjango | userW2E  | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 |
```

However if I do `\dt`

```
List of relations
 Schema |               Name               | Type  |  Owner

--------+----------------------------------+-------+----------
 public | account_registeremailaddress     | table | postgres
```

So I am trying

```
ALTER TABLE account_registeremailaddress OWNER TO userW2E;
```

And get error

```
ERROR:  role "userw2e" does not exist
```

Im new to postgres and a bit unsure on how to get my tables owned by user `userw2e`

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`userW2E` is identifier here, in case of mixed case, use double quotes:

```
ALTER TABLE account_registeremailaddress OWNER TO "userW2E";
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-table.html

> SQL is case **insensitive** about key words and identifiers, except when
>   identifiers are double-quoted to preserve the case

emphasis mine

Also https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS